# Как сделать "безопасный" звук в iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть кнопка по нажатию на которую нужно сделать щелчок. Если использовать системный звук как на клавиатуре.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1123)
```

То он будет играть его с одной громкостью независимо от громкости устройства. Это очень круто.

При это если создать звук через AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID, то он 
 уже будет зависеть от громкости устройства. На 100% громкости такой щелчок откровенно раздражает.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf")
var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url as CFURL, &soundID)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
```

Я знаю что в AudioServicesPlaySystemSound нет возможности изменять громкость и apple рекомендует использовать AVAudioPlayer, но как там добавиться такого "безопасного звука", чтобы его было слышно при 10% и при этом он не раздражал при 100%?

Comment: Я попробовал так сделать, но системные настройки звука всегда перебивают программные. Т.е. если пользователь установит минимальный звук, даже player.volume = 1 будет звучать очень тихо.
С обратной проблемой справится легче - можно проверять какая громкость установлена в системе.
А вы не хотите взять пример с твиттера и использовать вибрацию?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk я сейчас использую AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1123) . Хотелось бы конечно кастомный звук но удобство для пользователей важнее